# Is that Carousel of bootstrap not able to be used in IE?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3.02, what's the solution for using the carousel in IE?

Comment: You need to add more information, i.e. code of your carousel, IE version ...

Comment: please make sure of the links(js and css) added to your web page

Comment: please try to post your code and fiddle

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: Bootstrap exclusively uses CSS3 for its animations, but Internet Explorer 8 & 9 don't support the necessary CSS properties. Thus, there are no slide transition animations when using these browsers. We have intentionally decided not to include jQuery-based fallbacks for the transitions.I found above info, is that means we cannot use carousel in IE?

Comment: You can use another carousel plugin which are supported by IE @NiceGirl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)

> **Transition animations not supported in Internet Explorer 8 & 9**
>
> Bootstrap exclusively uses CSS3 for its animations, but Internet
>   Explorer 8 & 9 don't support the necessary CSS properties. Thus, there
>   are no slide transition animations when using these browsers. We have
>   intentionally decided not to include jQuery-based fallbacks for the
>   transitions.

You can try this: http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified which is fully responsive and supported by IE7 also.

Comment: I can't compare them? You have to decide it your self

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

CSS:

```
 <link href="bootstrap-3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap-3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

HTML:

```
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="..." alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="..." alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
                ...
            </div>

            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
<script src="bootstrap-3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Transition animations not supported in Internet Explorer 8 & 9

Comment: Yes you are rite! I m using IE 11